# Handling Back Button Press during Transition of an Activity which uses Animation

Tags: android, performance

Back Button Navigation problem:
when pressing Back button 
while the activity is getting animated, if the back button is pressed, it will to navigate to previous activity twice. How to resolve it?

This is our Code

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrugHelp.class);
    ActivitySwitcher.animationOut(findViewById(R.id.container),getWindowManager(),
                new AnimationFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationFinished() {
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   this.finish();
}
```

If it still go back twice, set a boolean to true when you're starting your animation, and in the function above, add

```
if(!yourBoolean){
   this.finish();
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `DrugHelp` was the `Activity` previous to this one. It was probably never finished so it is still on the stack. If this is the case, simply finishing this `Activivty` will take you to the previous one that hasn't been finished. You can also use `Intent Flags` to bring that one to the front of the stack if it already exists.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrugHelp.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

You also could use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` if you want to make sure that all other `Activities` on the stack are taken off.

[ReorderToFront](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

[Other intent flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

if it is just previous activity you are launching in side `onAnimationFinished`, then don't call startActivity, just finish the current activity only